# How to get tab active on page load -laravel

Tags: html, laravel

How can i get my first selected when i land on the page? When i land on the page, i have to select a tab before but is there a way i can have the first tab already selected when i land on the page?

when i load the page, i have my tabs showing but none of them are active until i click on them. Is there a way i can have the first tab active as the page loads.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">

          <div  class="nav-tabs-custom">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            @foreach($hotels as $hotel)

               <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $hotel->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$hotel->name!!}</a></li>
               @endforeach


            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
            @foreach($hotels as $hotel)

              <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_{{ $hotel->id }}">

              @foreach($hotel->waiters as $waiter)


            <label class="mylabel" >  {{$waiter->name}} </label>

             </div>
            @endforeach     
              </div>    

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You have to be more specific.What exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: this is not a clear question

Comment: @PedroFaria99  when i load the page, i have my tabs showing but none of them are active until i click on them. Is there a way i can have the first tab active as the page loads.

Comment: @AliinsanSoyaslan, please look at my recent comment

Comment: thanks for update now it's clear, i will post my ideas as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the active class that is added to every tab it should be just for one like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">

      <div  class="nav-tabs-custom">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        @foreach($hotels as $hotel)

           <li ><a href="#tab_{{ $hotel->id }}" data-toggle="tab" >{!!$hotel->name!!}</a></li>
           @endforeach


        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($hotels as $key => $hotel)
          <div class="tab-pane {{ $key==0 ? 'active' : ''}}" id="tab_{{ $hotel->id }}">
              @foreach($hotel->waiters as $waiter)
                  <label class="mylabel" >  {{$waiter->name}} </label>
              @endforeach     
         </div>
        @endforeach     
          </div>    

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is working but the tab doesn't show it is selected , the items under that tab do show alright

Comment: Yes i think there is a problem in the question code :p , i added `@endforeach` to it check the update !!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not realted to php or laravel, this question is more related to css-bootstrap and jquery.You can add below js to your code and remove active **active** class from hardcoded blade-html, I think this is a more proper solution :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tab-pane').each(function(tab,index){
    if(index==0){
     tab.addClass('active');
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: yes you are right ALI, this question is related to front end not backend